# Deploy a flask application alongside a Django application with uwsgi + nginx

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I'm trying to deploy a simple flask app in a server where is currently deployed a django app.

The django app works okay, but with the flask app shows 404 error, although I've done the correct settings and I don't see any error shown in the logs.

Currently, this is my app2.ini file

my app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='::')
```

wsgi.py

```
from flaskapp.app import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name mysite.com;

    # Let's Encrypt
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/html;
    }

    # Everything else -> SSL
    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}


server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;

    server_name mysite.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem;

    client_max_body_size 256m;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @uwsgi;
    }

    location @uwsgi {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/app/app/uwsgi.sock;
    }

    location /flask/ {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/app2/app/flaskapp/uwsgi.sock;
    }
}
```

my app2.ini file:

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /home/app2/app/flaskapp/uwsgi.sock
chdir = /home/app2/app
wsgi-file = flaskapp/wsgi.py
touch-reload = flaskapp/wsgi.py
venv = /home/app2/pyvenv
processes = 4
threads = 2
chmod-socket = 666
daemonize=true
vacuum = true
uid = app2
gid = app2
callable = app
```

tree:

```
flaskapp
├── app.py
├── __init__.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── app.cpython-35.pyc
│   └── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
├── uwsgi.sock
└── wsgi.py
```

Everything seems to work, when I try to go to mysite.com/flask this is the output of the uwsgi log file

```
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.14-debian (64bit) on [Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019] ***
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - compiled with version: 6.3.0 20170516 on 17 March 2018 15:41:47
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - os: Linux-4.9.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.168-1+deb9u2 (2019-05-13)
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - nodename: devuan
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - machine: x86_64
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - clock source: unix
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - pcre jit disabled
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - detected number of CPU cores: 1
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - current working directory: /
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - writing pidfile to /run/uwsgi/app/app2/pid
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi-core
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - setgid() to 1001
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - setuid() to 1001
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - chdir() to /home/app2/app
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - your processes number limit is 7928
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - your memory page size is 4096 bytes
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - detected max file descriptor number: 1024
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /run/uwsgi/app/app2/socket fd 3
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - uwsgi socket 1 bound to UNIX address /home/app2/app/flaskapp/uwsgi.sock fd 5
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - Python version: 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39)  [GCC 6.3.0 20170516]
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - Set PythonHome to /home/app2/pyvenv
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - Python main interpreter initialized at 0x5643c89a0f90
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - python threads support enabled
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - mapped 415360 bytes (405 KB) for 8 cores
Tue Jun  4 12:58:45 2019 - *** Operational MODE: preforking+threaded ***
Tue Jun  4 12:58:46 2019 - WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0x5643c89a0f90 pid: 17448 (default app)
Tue Jun  4 12:58:46 2019 - *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
Tue Jun  4 12:58:46 2019 - spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 17448)
Tue Jun  4 12:58:46 2019 - spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 17487, cores: 2)
Tue Jun  4 12:58:46 2019 - spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 17488, cores: 2)
Tue Jun  4 12:58:46 2019 - spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 17491, cores: 2)
Tue Jun  4 12:58:46 2019 - spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 17492, cores: 2)
[pid: 17491|app: 0|req: 1/1] 2a0a:e5c1:115::42 () {44 vars in 767 bytes} [Tue Jun  4 12:58:51 2019] GET /flask/ => generated 232 bytes in 14 msecs (HTTP/1.1 404) 2 headers in 72 bytes (2 switches on core 0)
```

The nginx.log file when i try to reach mysite.com/flask:

```
2a0a:e5c1:115::42 - - [04/Jun/2019:13:14:58 +0000] "GET /flask/ HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0"
```

Let me know if you see something, I've been trying to solve it but no clue what else can I do.

Comment: Are they both listening on the same port?

Comment: Yes.. also tried to set the port in the .ini file but returned me an error.. any advice on how to change it? Or maybe other conf to put in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well In case anyone else face this issue I managed to do it by including this conf in the /flask location:

```
location /flask {
    rewrite ^/flask(.*) $1 break; # IMPORTANT!
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/home/app2/app/flaskapp/uwsgi.sock;
}
```